# Create TTL pulse with button press

Tags: pulse, ttl, hobbyist

Is there any way to get a 5V TTL signal (pulse of whatever duration, could even be a boxcar) from a button press with a very simple circuit or with some consumer device?

I need this to do some debugging, and am a bit surprised — given how ubiquitous TTL pulses are in electronics — that I can't find anything for the simplest possible instantiation of creating such a pulse. I would imagine a lot of people need such a device just to test stuff out  I have found a number of questions here (e.g. [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/631912/how-to-make-a-ttl-low-pulse-of-100-ns-to-1-%ce%bcs-with-a-simple-rc-on-a-74ls04-inver)), but they seem to address much more specific use cases.

I guess I could just connect a few batteries in series to get to about 5V and just connect/disconnect the wires... But that would give me a lot of current as well, in addition to being pretty finicky to operate.

Comment: Yes? A button already does this. If you connect it to 5V and a pull-down resistor, or vice versa.

Comment: well, for TTL you presumably want it connected to ground with a pull-up, because TTL likes to sink current into outputs and not source it. If you just want a 5V pulse, then either way works.

Comment: What is "a boxcar"?

Comment: If looking for a consumer device, I'd probably guess that Adafruit would be the place to look. (No idea if they sell it, but I associate them as trafficking in these kinds of products since it fits their customer base well, to my mind.) They do have [a blog](https://blog.adafruit.com/2020/04/22/ultimate-guide-to-switch-debounce-eejournaltfm-maxmaxfield/) on the topic. I used to use the 74121 and/or 74123, but those may be getting scarce. Have you looked at the 74123?

Answer (score 1):

Make a simple pulser with a [microswitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miniature_snap-action_switch) and a flip flop to create a debounced TTL signal. Usually you can make something like this out of found parts. You'll need some clips and/or a probe to connect to the power of the circuit under test and inject the signal.
[image]

Image source: https://www.eejournal.com/article/ultimate-guide-to-switch-debounce-part-5/

Answer (score 0):

Many people use the GPIO pins of their computer for this; if not available, then handshake lines of a USB TTL serial port might work for you.

There are a great number of such things available:
[image]
Google search for `usb ttl serial port`